# PHP CURL. Как исправить Could not resolve host?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, curl

Мой сайт генерирует множество запросов к VK API. После обновления CURL до версии 7.72.0 периодически стала появляться ошибка -
Could not resolve host: pu.vk.com
Причем, часть запросов "пролетает" нормально, затем появляется все больше и больше этих ошибок. Перезапуск apache или сервера в целом решает проблему, но не на долго.

Есть варианты, как избавиться от такой ошибки?

Comment: а хост pu.vk.com на самом деле существует? возможно, Ваш сайт генерирует запросы на основе какой то информации (парсинга) и где то происходит сбой.

Comment: Добавьте в хосты своей ОС запись с IP pu.vk.com. ip можно получить с помощью утилиты ping например. Для этого домена оно будет 87.240.129.180.

Comment: Хост существует, это 100%
Добавив запись, вероятно, удастся решить проблему, но способ топорный получается, хотелось бы в причинах разобраться 